# java check if list of object contains object with concrete name

Tags: java, list, object, equals, hashcode

I have list of objects:

```
List<City> cities = city.getList();
```

I would like to remove duplicates (where duplicates mean objects with the same value of parameter `name` and different (`id`, and other parameters);

I have code for that:

```
for(City c: cities) {
    System.out.println("analise " + c.name);
    if(!temp.contains(c)) {
        temp.add(c);
    }
}
```

I've wrote for that hashCode() and equals() method:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}
```

...

```
  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof GenericDictionary))return false;
        GenericDictionary otherMyClass = (GenericDictionary) other;
        if(this.name == otherMyClass.name) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But it dosnt apply it. It use object.equals() method instead of mine

Comment: You don't need to override hashcode for arraylist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in String comparison :

```
if(this.name == otherMyClass.name)
```

Change it to :

```
if(this.name.equals(otherMyClass.name))
```

Comment: or just `return name.equals(otherMyClass.name);`

Comment: It works. :D Thanks. Now I see my mistake in string comparsion :D